# Converting into python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am slightly confused as I am trying to use a regex which I have tested and works but does not appear to work in Python

```
^(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])/(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$
```

I am trying to match mm/yy and dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Wow, the son of Bob Marley is there, stay tuned folks ! ^^

Comment: Where/how have you tested this regex? It doesn't look right to me at all.

Comment: Do you have that as a raw string? For example,  `regex = r'^\d'`

Comment: @cricket_007: Always a good question, but in this case it's moot since there are no backslashes at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should work and is similar to what you were doing.

```
([01]?[0-9])\/([0-3]?[0-9])\/([0-9]{2,4})
```

Comment: Is it possible to extend this for MM/YY ?

Comment: Sure. Just remove the second part: `([01]?[0-9])\/([0-9]{2,4})`

Answer (score 0):

Bro try this,

```
'(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/([0]*[1-9]|[1][012])/([0-9]{2,4})'
```

I have tested this, you can check it on

http://ideone.com/M0Ojqx

```
import re
myString = "Todays date is 31/12/2015 and tomorrow's date is 1/1/15"
myList = re.findall('(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/([0]*[1-9]|[1][012])/([0-9]{2,4})',myString)
print myList
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ^(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])/(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$
> ```
>
> I am trying to match mm/yy and dd/mm/yyyy

Your regex already matches *dd/mm/yyyy*. To also match *mm/yy*, you just have to make the *dd/* part optional by enclosing it in `(?:` `)?` as you did with the century digits.

```
regex = '^(?:(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/)?(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])/(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$'
import re
print re.match(regex, '30/12/15').group(0,1,2)
#('30/12/15', '30', '12')

print re.match(regex, '12/15').group(0,1,2)
#('12/15', None, '12')
```

Answer (score -2):

Your regex (not reggae: was funny in the title) syntax is already python compliant.

How did you use it ? Show us your code and tell us what you expect !

A simpler approach :

```
>>> import re
>>> x = '30/12/15'
>>> print(re.search('^(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2,4})$', x).groups())
('30', '12', '15')
>>> x = '30/12/2015'
>>> print(re.search('^(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2,4})$', x).groups())
('30', '12', '2015')
```

You can start your work on this and elaborate deeper and deeper while the regex still match between tests

### NOTE

do you understand this ?

```
(?:  )
```

this for grouping without capturing.

If you expect '15' to be returned, don't use this

Last but not least, when regex get so complicated, use python itself  :

```
>>> x = '30/12/2015'
>>> a = x.split("/")
>>> if a[0] >=1 and a[0] <= 31 ... # to be completed
```

Comment: This is derogatory. I honestly can't distinguish the rant in your answer, from the actual answer itself (if there even is one). If you can't bother to answer with something that will help, then please, don't answer at all.

Comment: No criticism nor derogatory here. I give the better clue to resolv the problem : use python instead of complicated regex.